# In the other hand or on the other hand

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

What is the difference between the following? Also, if both:

1. *in the other hand* and
2. *on the other hand*

are correct. And what is the reason?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

***On the other hand*** is a set phrase meaning "in a way that is different or opposite from the previous argument." (Source: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/on-the-other-hand)

> She might really love me. ***On the other hand***, she might really hate me.

***In the other hand*** is a valid, grammatical phrase, but it's not a set phrase. It only has its literal meaning, that something is literally in the other hand.

> He took the basketball ***in the other hand*** as he drove to the hoop.

If you're still wondering "why," then you might need to have a better understanding of a what a ***set phrase*** is. Here are a couple of pages that explain this.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/set+phrase
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/set_phrase